# Efficiently finding "unfounded edges" in a strongly connected graph

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

While implementing a debugger I've encountered a problem I need to solve concerning dependency graphs. I've simplified it as follows:

Consider a **strongly connected** graph G = (V,E).

- We define a subset of vertices S ⊆ V as *source vertices*.
- We call an edge **e** = (**a**,**b**) *unfounded* if there is no **simple path** from any source vertex to **b** that includes **e**. In other words, all paths from a source vertex that include edge **e**, must include vertex **b** at least twice.

The problem:

- Find all unfounded edges in G.

There are some obvious ways to solve this inefficiently (e.g. a depth-first traversal for each edge in G), but I was wondering if there was any **O(|E|)** approach. I've been struggling with this for a while and I keep "almost" solving it in linear time. Perhaps that's impossible? I have no idea what the lower bound on efficiency is, and I was hoping some readers here could help me discover some efficient approaches.

An illustrative example is a simple 3-cycle.  Pick any one vertex as the source vertex. The edge coming into the source vertex is unfounded.

Comment: One optimisation that might get rid of many *founded* edges quickly: Run a BFS from some source node $r$, and discard every edge $uv$ for which $d(r, v) = d(r, u) + 1$ -- all such edges strictly increase the distance from $r$. Optionally repeat for other source nodes if edges remain. You will still need to check each edge $uv$ that remains (by, e.g., reversing all edge directions, deleting $v$, and running a DFS from $u$ to see if any source is reachable).

Comment: Two improvements: (1) Whenever the BFS encounters another source node, do not add any of its out-edges to the queue. Running this modified BFS from all source vertices is as good as running the original BFS from all source vertices, but now takes only $O(|E|)$ *total* time :-) (2) In the absence of self-loops, you can also delete edges $uv$ for which $d(r, u) = d(r, v)$, since there must exist some path of strictly increasing-distance vertices from $r$ to $u$, and the final edge cannot point back to itself or any of these earlier vertices.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that computing [graph dominators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)) will solve your problem. This can be done in $O(|E|\log |V|)$ time (or even faster, though they describe the faster algorithm as "sophisticated") using a 1979 algorithm by Lengauer and Tarjan, which is (at least currently) [described here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/357062.357071) (21 pages -- I have only read the first few pages myself).

Add a new "start" node with an out-edge to every source node, run the dominator algorithm to determine dominators for every node, and then check each edge $uv$: $uv$ is unfounded if and only if $v$ dominates $u$. (Each of these checks can be done in constant time using a [lowest common ancestor (LCA) algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor), although that may be overkill here -- for an edge $uv$, we only care about whether or not $LCA(u, v) = v$.)

Comment: This seems promising, thank you! I'll verify whether this works. It's interesting to see a relationship to control flow graphs (the graphs in my problem domain are data dependency graphs).

Comment: You're welcome :)